# Laravel 5 Elixir: copy all files except some

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I would like to copy all the files from a directory to the public directory except some files.

Example:

```
/views 
   file1.html
   file2.html
   file3.html
   file4.html
   ......
   fileN.html
```

I want to copy all files from the view folder to public view directory except **file1.html** and **file2.html**

I could use

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.copy('views', 'public/views');
});
```

But it copy all the files. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use array with negation in elixir:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.copy(['views/**.html' , '!views/file1.html' ,'!views/file2.html'], 'public/views');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i found a solution. In case anyone interested

```
gulp.src(['views/**.html' , '!views/file1.html' ,'!views/file2.html']).pipe(gulp.dest('public/views'));
```